# Multiple SUM results in single query

Tags: apex, soql

I have a custom object `object__c` which has three fields `total_1__c`, `total_2__c` and `total_3__c`. 
I want to query on all `object__c` records to get SUM of `total_1__c`,`total_2__c` and `total_3__c`. It can be done using 3 aggregate queries, but is it possible to get sum of these 3 fields separately in a single query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why can't you use this query?

```
SELECT sum(total_1__c), sum(total_2__c), sum(total_3__c) FROM object__c
```